# RewriteRule for url causes Facebook login to break

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk, oauth-2.0

I have a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ bus.php?location=$1
```

When I try to login from that page domain.com/b/23467 it hits the oauth page and sends it right back and I'm still logged out.

What I think is the problem is FB is sending it back wrong.I have a domain.com/?logout=yes to log me out if logged in and a domain.com/?login=yes to log me in.  When I try domain.com/b/23443?logout=yes that does not work....but domain.com/b/23443&logout=yes works. Which makes sense, but Facebook sends back the url to oauth and I noticed the return url is a "?" after the url and not a "&".

Hopefully this makes sense.  The rewriterule is not really working but there has to be something I can do to have this work for me?

Comment: Accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark at the left if it solved your problem!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try enabling query strings on the rewrite rule...

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ bus.php?location=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That was a fast answer and worked perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, please click the tick icon next to this answer